# Using a CTE to provide a cumulative total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have a table with some forenames in:

```
SELECT * FROM d;

Forename
--------------------------------
Robert
Susan
Frances
Kate
May
Alex
Anna
```

I want to pull a cumulative total of name lengths alphabetically. So far I have:

```
WITH    Names ( RowNum, Forename, ForenameLength )
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY forename ) AS RowNum ,
                        Forename ,
                        LEN(forename) AS ForenameLength
               FROM     d
             )
    SELECT  RowNum ,
            Forename ,
            ForenameLength ,
            ISNULL(ForenameLength + ( SELECT    ISNULL(SUM(ForenameLength),0)
                                      FROM      Names
                                      WHERE     RowNum < n.RowNum
                                    ), 0) AS CumLen
    FROM    NAMES n;

RowNum               Forename                         ForenameLength CumLen
-------------------- -------------------------------- -------------- -----------
1                    Alex                             4              4
2                    Anna                             4              8
3                    Frances                          7              15
4                    Kate                             4              19
5                    May                              3              22
6                    Robert                           6              28
7                    Susan                            5              33
```

But I understand that it should be possible to do this (recursively) within the CTE. Anyone know how this could be achieved?

N.B. whilst we are developing on 2012, the current live system is 2008 so any solution would need to be backwards compatible at least in the short term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on SQL Server 2012 and should use `sum() over()` instead.

```sql
select row_number() over(order by d.Forename) as RowNum,
       d.Forename,
       len(d.Forename) as ForenameLength,
       sum(len(d.Forename)) over(order by d.Forename rows unbounded preceding) as CumLen
from d
order by d.Forename;
```

Result:

```
RowNum   Forename     ForenameLength CumLen
-------- ------------ -------------- -----------
1        Alex         4              4
2        Anna         4              8
3        Frances      7              15
4        Kate         4              19
5        May          3              22
6        Robert       6              28
7        Susan        5              33
```

Update:

If you for some reason absolutely want a recursive version it could look something like this:

```sql
with C as
(
  select top(1)
    1 as RowNum,
    d.Forename,
    len(d.Forename) as ForenameLength,
    len(d.Forename) as CumLen
  from d
  order by d.Forename      
  union all
  select d.RowNum,
         d.Forename,
         d.ForenameLength,
         d.CumLen      
  from (
       select C.RowNum + 1 as RowNum,
              d.Forename,
              len(d.Forename) as ForenameLength,
              C.CumLen + len(d.Forename) as CumLen,
              row_number() over(order by d.ForeName) as rn
       from d
         inner join C
           on C.Forename < d.Forename
       ) as d
  where d.rn = 1
)
select C.RowNum,
       C.Forename,
       C.ForenameLength,
       C.CumLen
from C;
```

Adapted from [Performance Tuning the Whole Query Plan](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan) by Paul White.

Comment: First value should be 0. At least that's what OP has given us.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas True, but I don't understand why so I will just assume that is a typo.

Comment: Sorry, yes - the first cumulative value should indeed have been 4.

Comment: To save confusion, I've fixed my original code and output

Comment: Just Perfect !! i needed time to understand this quite complex query using cte and row_number() in a very smart way ! Gains perfs++, Thanks !